# How to return rows listed in descending order of COUNT(*)?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, query-optimization

I have a table called `foo` with these fields:

```
- id

- type

- parentId
```

I want to select a list of parent IDS, in the descending order of their `COUNT(*)` of how many times they appear in the table. Something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT parentId FROM `foo` 
ORDER BY (COUNT(parentId) DESC where parentId = parentId)
```

How can this be done in the most efficient way and putting the least load on the server?

There can be thousands-hundreds of thousands of records in the table, so manually going through each record is not acceptable..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply by applying a `GROUP BY` clause, and assuming you have an index , `FOREIGN KEY`, or `PRIMARY KEY` on `parentId`, the performance should be quite good.  (`parentId` looks like it is likely a `FORIEGN KEY`, so be sure to define the constraint to enforce indexing).

```
SELECT `parentId`
FROM `foo`
GROUP BY `parentId`
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can this be done in the most efficient way and putting the least load on the server?

The key is the **the most efficient way**.

Not a Count() for sure, but most efficient is... to read a field, which you are storing the Count result. You can update it with a trigger or after insert.

Especially when

> There can be thousands-hundreds of thousands of records in the table